# Stack Overflow does not render correctly from work

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Whenever I use Stack Overflow or related sites from work the site does not display properly. At first I figured it was part of my company's mission to eventually block any site that could be useful in getting actual work done, but other folks can access the site fine. I've cleared my internet files, cookies etc. Any insight into what is happening and how to fix it is appreciated.

I'm using the same computer from my home network fine so I think something is getting blocked. Here's a screen shot of what I see:

[image]

And here's the error messages:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR
3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC EA 2; SLCC1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Tablet PC 2.0; MS-RTC LM 8) Timestamp: Wed, 15 Jun 2011 13:31:24 UTC


Message: Invalid character Line: 1 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=005820c36f6e


Message: 'StackExchange' is undefined Line: 20 Char: 9 Code: 0 URI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell


Message: Invalid character Line: 1 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/tageditor.js?v=8813fe530cd0


Message: 'StackExchange' is undefined Line: 185 Char: 5 Code: 0 URI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell

    <script type="text/javascript">
    StackExchange.init({"stackAuthUrl":"http://stackauth.com","serverTime":1308144196,"styleCode":true,"site":{"name":"Stack Overflow","description":"Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers"},"user":{"isRegistered":true,"guid":"58b700e7-2fe4-45a7-a737-2d817c641a15","gravatar":"\u003cimg src=\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/30f62a443fa50812e6274f8afa8a5479?s=50&d=identicon&r=PG\" height=\"50\" width=\"50\" alt=\"\"\u003e","profileUrl":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/135965/chad-miller","fkey":"ec57bf7b9c9c5f4e378a0e00c8af499d","inboxUnviewedCount":0}});
    StackExchange.using.setCacheBreakers({"js/prettify-full.js":"dcf6d862901d","js/moderator.js":"6cc48504dab8","js/full-anon.js":"54059128f403","js/full.js":"e3575d1956dc","js/wmd.js":"fff19522f52d","js/third-party/jquery.autocomplete.min.js":"e5f01e97f7c3"});
</script>
```

Comment: If you're able to use a non-IE browser, does it also have problems?

Comment: I wish I could use a non-IE browser, but stuck with IE 8. If I use the same laptop from home on my home network--works fine

Comment: Do you have Fiddler?

Comment: And if you *do* have Fiddler, it does have a rule to "disable compression" or somesuch; do you get the same error even with gzip disabled?

Comment: I had the same issue. By downloading Fiddler2, applying the 'Remove All Encodings' rule on the Rules menu, and clearing IE's cache the problem was removed. Now I need to try to convince someone to fix the root cause...

Comment: hmm, I cleared IE cache usign Fiddler2 and its working.

Answer (score 5):

You have a proxy that is messing up the Javascript on http://sstatic.net.

What response do you get for http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=005820c36f6e?
(In particular, the first few characters)

I get

```
window.StackExchange={};if(top!=self){top.location.replace(document.location);alert("For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.")}StackExchange.init=(function(){var a=function(e){if(!window.jQuery){if(document.readyState!="complete"){setTimeout(function(){a(e)},1000);return}var d=document.createElement("div");d.id="noscript-padding";var f=document.createElement("div");f.id="noscript-warning";f.innerHTML=e+" requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.";document.body.insertBefore(d,document.body.firstChild);document.body.appendChild(f)}};var c=function(){$(document).keyup(function(d){if(d.which==27){$("#lightbox, .error-notification, .popup, .share-tip, .esc-remove").fadeOutAndRemove();$(".esc-hide").fadeOut();if(window.genuwine&&genuwine.isVisible()){genuwine.click()}if(window.profileLink){profileLink.hide()}}})};return function(d){StackExchange.options=d;var e=d.serverTime-(new Date()).getTime()/1000;a(d.site.name);$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});StackExchange.init.createJqueryExtensions();$(function(){c();StackExchange.using(StackExchange.options.user.isAnonymous?"anonymous":"loggedIn", ...
```

Comment: I get bunch of errors when clicking the stub.js link above. On another machine a home using FireFox I get the same output as you.

Comment: What's the contents of the file in Fiddler?

Comment: Well it seems to workign now. I can post the Fiddler contents, but I thinking maybe I didn't clear my cache correctly or IE didn't, but Fiddler did.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't your corporate proxy dropping "gzip" header?

I guess those file always returns gzipped contents, so you got error on first character which is in binary.

> Message: Invalid character Line: 1 **Char: 1** Code: 0

Comment: Not sure, I'll ping my network guys

Answer (score 1):

Coming in late, but I discovered that on my own work PC, this problem was caused by turning on "InPrivate Filtering" in IE. Turning that off lets Stack Exchange sites work normally.