# Why would I lose all styling for StackExchange sites in IE9?

Tags: support, user-interface, design, internet-explorer-9

In IE9 on my work PC, this is what I get when browsing StackOverflow, or any StackExchange site:

[image: Unstyled StackOverflow Home Page]

FireFox is fine. IE9 at home is also fine. IE9 at work was fine, until a few weeks ago.

I've tried deleting or resetting everything in IE9 via Cog Icon -> Internet Options -> General -> Delete, and Cog Icon -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Reset, but no change.

I've tried accessing the link to the stylesheet that is in the homepage - http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=2c291e18c3f6. In FireFox it comes back fine. In IE9 it comes back as garbage, but it looks like it's just the CSS file gzipped. However, when I unzip it using the following F# script:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.IO.Compression

let readGzip path = 
    seq { use stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)
          use gZipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress)
          use reader = new StreamReader(gZipStream)
          while not (reader.EndOfStream) do yield reader.ReadLine() }

let write (path:string) (lines:string seq) =
    use writer = new StreamWriter(path)
    lines |> Seq.iter (writer.WriteLine)

let desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
Path.Combine(desktopPath, "all.css")
|> readGzip
|> write (Path.Combine(desktopPath, "allunzipped.css"))
```

The CSS comes back fine at the beginning of the file, up to the kbd style. But then it goes a bit strange.

[image: CSS Comparison]

As far as I know my decompression code is OK. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably same issue with this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95428/stack-overflow-does-not-render-correctly-from-work

Comment: @YOU - yep, it certainly seems similar. Gonna grab fiddler now and have a play.

Comment: Can you upload that gzipped file somewhere if you don't mind, I liked to test unpacking here.

Comment: @YOU - try this http://www.mediafire.com/?wvldxznmtl2lhr2

Comment: @YOU - I downloaded Fiddler2 in the end and applying the 'Remove All Encodings' rule got it working in IE9. Don't know if I'll be able to fix the root cause though.

Comment: I see, and the file is somehow broken and I can't unpack it, and filesize is 11,688 and actual working one is 11,683 bytes.

Comment: btw how did you save the file? Save As or copy pasted to text editors? all of the NULL characters became spaces in your all.css gzipped file.

Comment: @YOU I typed in the link in IE9, up popped notepad.exe containing the compressed file, and I just did File-> Save As with default settings (ANSI encoding, so I'm guessing even if it changed it, it shouldn't have added anything?).

Comment: I see, I also think "Save As" should be fine.